# ManyToOne Outer Join in a single query (1 to 0 relationship)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm struggling with a mapping problem in hibernate.

Got This mapping between 2 tables

Table 1

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="CNT_ID",referencedColumnName = "CNT_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Table2 table2;
```

Table 2

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="table2")
private List<Table1> table1List;
```

I'm making a query like this :

```
select table1 from Table1 table1 left outer join table1.table2
```

The result is ok : got all data in table1 and some table2 (some table1 don't have link to table2) so the outer join is ok.

The problem is that hibernate is making one query to catch all table1 and after 1 query for each line result for table1.
So If I have 100lines in table 1, hibernate is making 101 queries ...

Do I miss something ? I'm working with oracle database, also try the (+) operator (outer operator in oracle) but hibernate didn't want it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: No time to write a good answer so just a comment -> use left join fetch instead. The fetch strategies do only apply for none custom queries if I remember correct.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to change fetch of `table2` to `FetchType.LAZY`. Always do so, if you don't have a good reasons to eagerly fetching a `@ManyToOne` part of the association.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CNT_ID",referencedColumnName = "CNT_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Table2 table2;
```

If you need to get `Table1` that have some properties in `table2` just use a join

`from Table1 table1 left join table1.table2 table2 
    where table2.someProperty = :somePropertyValue`

If you need to load `table2` use a join fetch

`from Table1 table1 left join fetch table1.table2 table2 
    where table2.someProperty = :somePropertyValue`

if you need only part of `table2` use projections

`select table1.property1, table1.property2, table2.someProperty
    from Table1 table1 left join table1.table2 table2 
    where table2.someProperty = :somePropertyValue`

If you will use a projections you can use a `new` syntax to populate DTO objects

`select new com.pack.TableDto(table1.property1, table1.property2, table2.someProperty)
    from Table1 table1 left join table1.table2 table2 
    where table2.someProperty = :somePropertyValue`

or you can use a transformer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that when I'm doing a left join, I only retrieve table1 with a link to table 2, some of my table1 data don't have a link to table2 (the relation is more 1 or 0). This is why I've tried with an outer fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Table2`(parent) is EAGER and you're selecting from `Table1`, for every row in `Table1` Hibernate will issue a query to populate `Table2` reference. One solution is to join fetch `table2` reference on the first query. 
This is a known behavior of Hibernate when using HQL(with Criteria API I don't think it applies).
I have blogged on detail about it [here](http://www.javacents.com/2015/11/07/orm-pitfall-number-1-with-non-lazy-references/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Isah, I'm going to look at your blog, will update my answer after to tell if it's working.

Comment: I've answered to v.ladynev, I've read your blog, the problem with left join is that I only got table1 data with a link to table2 not table1 data with no table2

Comment: Use `inner join fetch table1.table2` instead of `left join fetch`.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I've just tried the inner join fetch but the problem still remains, only getting table1 with a link to table 2.

Comment: `inner join fetch` - returns table1 which has table2 data. 
`left join fetch` - returns table1 data with or without table2 data. That's all.